# Display Twitter Feed of user

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, twitter-feed

I wanted to display twitter feed like in image [image]

Is it necessary to do **"OAuth"** for this?? I am trying to do "OAuth" in using [this url](http://twitter.com/oauth_clients/new). 
It is giving:

```
Access denied Sorry, you're not allowed to access that page.
```

Twitter feed should be of user which i will give username not who are logged in simulator or device. I am following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/twitter-api-iphone--mobile-2829)

Comment: There is a bold comment saying "With the release of iOS 5, this article is now outdated. Moving forward, you should seriously consider using the Twitter Framework that ships with the iOS 5 SDK. Only consider implementing the solution demonstrated here if you must support users on older versions of iOS."

Comment: @SebastianWramba i know that tutorial is outdated but i wanted to know it necessary to do OAuth for this can you please tell me?? OAuth giving "Access denied Sorry, you're not allowed to access that page". and for iOS 5 do you know about any helpful tutorial i should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Twitter offers applications the ability to issue authenticated requests on behalf of the application itself" https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth

You can use  - [AFTweetFetcher](https://github.com/austinfitzpatrick/AFTweetFetcher) - "Simple class for retrieving tweets from twitter using their new 1.1 API without requiring the user to authenticate or have a twitter account stored on their device"

All you need: `ConsumerKey` and `ConsumerSecret`

Comment: i do not need to authenticate right using AFTweetFetcher right? than i am using consumerKey and consumerSecret which is in [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth) but its giving error Unable to verify your credentials

Comment: Error : {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=3&screen_name=NASA, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=3&screen_name=NASA, NSUnderlyingError=0xade65e0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}

Comment: it is done when i have changed ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret.

Comment: i have created new app [here](https://apps.twitter.com/app/new) to get new ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret. now it is working

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to authenticate.

Try this library https://github.com/nst/STTwitter if you don't want to use Apple's Twitter frameworks as this would require the user of the phone to have a twitter account.

Comment: i am trying to authenticate in [this link](https://apps.twitter.com/app/new) but when i click on create your twitter application nothing happend